# How to copy the content of a CFile to CMemFile?

Tags: mfc

How to copy the whole content of CFile into CMemFile in windows OS.
I tried below code to copy the contents.

```
CMemFile memFile;
bool b = memFile.Open( L"C:\\test.txt",  CFile::modeReadWrite);
int Length = memFile.GetLength();
unsigned char* buffer = new unsigned char[Length];
memFile.Read((void*)buffer,Length);
memFile.Close();
```

But memFile.GetLength returns 0. whereas if I try with CFile, GetLength()  returns some valid length.

```
CFile f;
bool b1 = f.Open( L"C:\\test.txt",  CFile::modeReadWrite);
int Lengh = f.GetLength();
f.Close();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please confirm that the file `"C:\test.txt"` exists beforehand

Comment: The code you show doesn't match neither question title nor description. The code samples use either `CMemFile` or `CFile`, but there is no copying between both.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve my requirement using below code.

```
CFile f;
bool b = f.Open( L"C:\\test.txt",  CFile::modeReadWrite);
int nLength = f.GetLength();
BYTE* buffer = new BYTE[nLength];
f.Read((void*)buffer,nLength);
f.Close();
CMemFile memFile;
memFile.Attach(buffer, nLength);
```

Comment: This uses the wrong allocator. As noted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmemfile-class#attach), *"to be compatible with the default implementation of `Alloc`, you must allocate the memory with the run-time library function `malloc` or `calloc`."* You need to stay compatible with the default `Alloc` implementation, as the call to `Attach` transfers ownership of the memory resource to the `CMemFile` instance. When that object gets destroyed, its `Free` implementation is invoked (calling `free`, which is incompatible with `operator new[]`).

Answer (score 0):

To copy the contents of a disk file into a memory buffer controlled by a `CMemFile` instance, the following steps are required:

- Open the file on disk, passing the correct options.
- Allocate memory for use by the `CMemFile` instance.
- Read disk contents into the `CMemFile`-controlled memory buffer.

The following is a possible implementation:

```cpp
// Open file on disk
// typeBinary is necessary to read the raw, untransformed contents
// shareDenyWrite is required to prevent the file from changing in between querying
//     its size and reading the contents
// osSequentialScan could be used to provide an access pattern hint to the OS
//     to allow it to better optimize the (potentially slow) disk accesses
CFile File( L"C:\\test.txt", CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeBinary | CFile::shareDenyWrite );
auto Length = File.GetLength();

// Construct CMemFile instance and allocate memory
CMemFile memFile();
auto buffer = memFile.Alloc( Length );
if ( !buffer ) {
    // Depending on your exception handling system, call AfxThrowMemoryException instead
    throw std::bad_alloc();
}
// Transfer ownership of the buffer to the CMemFile instance
memFile.Attach( buffer, Length );

// Read contents into memory buffer
// Note, that this is limited to file sizes smaller than 4 GB
File.Read( buffer, static_cast<UINT>( Length ) );
```

At that point the entire contents of the disk file have been read into the `CMemFile` instance' buffer, assuming that no exceptions were raised along the way. All resources are controlled by C++ objects, and no manual cleanup is required. When the `memFile` object goes out of scope, its memory is automatically released. When the `File` instance goes out of scope, the system-level file `HANDLE` is closed.